# Comparison of clustering methods on geodemographic classification

Tags: clustering, demography, geomarketing

Most geodemographic classification systems using K-means method for clustering and creating segments. For example, ESRI Tapestry(Business Analyst) is most using geodemographic system lately.

What about other clustering methods like CAMEO, ACORN, or Open geodemographics? Is there any way to compare clustering methods for geodemographics?

Comment: To which GIS  package does this question pertain?

Comment: ESRI's Tapestry Segmentation, CAMEO, ACORN, Open geodemographics..

Comment: Please **edit** the question in response to requests for clarification. It's not fair to those who would answer to need to mine the comments for critical information.